# How to get average value of a sequence using iterator in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, iterator

I am currently using pandas to manage a CSV file that contains data on vessel locations on a map. I have a Pandas data frame that looks like this (which is simplified):

| Index | Group | C_p |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 1 | 85 |
| 3 | 1 | 83 |
| 4 | 1 | 78 |
| 5 | 1 | 66 |
| 6 | 1 | 47 |
| 7 | 3 | 82 |
| 8 | 3 | 80 |
| 9 | 3 | 66 |

C_p is a confidence coefficient to judge if a vessel is parked.

The way to judge a parked vessel is like this:

If the average value of a  sequence of data's C_p is above `80`, this sequence of data is a parked vessel, and the minimum number of a sequence is above `3`.

So in this example, index 2 to 4 is a sequence of parked vessels because the average value of C_p is 82.67 which is above 80. Even though index 7 to 8, the average value of C_p is above 80, the sequence just has two elements so this is not a parked vessel.

So I want to get this:

| Index | Group | C_p | is_parked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 27 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 85 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 83 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 78 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 66 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 47 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 82 | 0 |
| 8 | 3 | 80 | 0 |
| 9 | 3 | 66 | 0 |

I attempt to change this method into a Leetcode question like:

```
for i in range(n - 2): # n is the element number of a group
    avg = (C_p[i] + C_p[i+1] + C_p[i+2]) / 3
    if avg >= 80:
        is_parked[i] = is_parked[i+1] = is_parked[i+2] = 1 # default value of is_parked is 0
```

But I have no idea how to Implement it with Pandas or Python.

So my question is:

1. Is there any way to implement this in Pandas?
2. If not, should I turn to Numpy or something else to get the results?

---

Edit: 1
[Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick)'s comment allows me to double-check my example and my method.

If C_p[5] = 78, it's still a parked vessel and it's computed on a per Group.

I hadn't considered that so my first attempt was wrong.
Here's my new attempt

```
for i in range(n):
    thisSUM = C_p[i]
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        thisSUM += C_p[j]
        avg = thisSUM / (j - i + 1)
        if avg >= 80 and j - i + 1 >= 3:
            for k in range(i, j+1):
                is_parked_check[k] = 1
```

Time complexity is O(n^3), which is not good.

Comment: What if `C_p[5] = 78`? Is that still a parked vessel (because the sequence from 2-5 has an average >= 80) or not parked (because the sequence from 3-5 has an average <= 80)?

Comment: Also, is this supposed to be computed on a per-`Group` basis or on all the data?

Comment: My attempt is wrong. If C_p[5] = 78, it's still a parked vessel and it's computed on a per Group. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) in a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). The first one is to compute the rolling average, we then check if the value is above the threshold. Then we reverse the Series and compute a rolling **max** to propagate the True/1 to the previous N-1 rows:

```
N = 3
threshold = 80

df['is_parked'] = (df.groupby('Group')['C_p']
                     .transform(
                        lambda s: s.rolling(N).mean().gt(threshold)[::-1]
                                   .rolling(N, min_periods=1).max()
                                   .astype(int)
                     )
                   )
```

Output:

```
   Index  Group  C_p  is_parked
0      1      1   27          0
1      2      1   85          1
2      3      1   83          1
3      4      1   78          1
4      5      1   66          0
5      6      1   47          0
6      7      3   82          0
7      8      3   80          0
8      9      3   66          0
```

Intermediates:

```
   Index  Group  C_p       formula        avg    >80  rev_roll
0      1      1   27           NaN        NaN  False         0
1      2      1   85           NaN        NaN  False         1
2      3      1   83  (83+85+27)/3  65.000000  False         1
3      4      1   78  (78+83+85)/3  82.000000   True         1
4      5      1   66  (66+78+83)/3  75.666667  False         0
5      6      1   47  (47+66+78)/3  63.666667  False         0
6      7      3   82           NaN        NaN  False         0
7      8      3   80           NaN        NaN  False         0
8      9      3   66  (66+80+82)/3  76.000000  False         0
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me but my first method was wrong. I add my new method in the recent edit.

Comment: @AndrewChao I believe my code is already doing what you want. I added some details, please double check and clarify if needed.